# Tomcat and Eclipse vs Intellij

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea, logback

I am working with Intellij but some of my co-workers don't. When I was writing install doc, I realized that Tomcat is not managed the same way on the two IDEs.

Which is a problem considering what happened next when I tried to set up our project on Eclipse.

Basically, on Intellij, you select a Tomcat on your computer and it will literally copy the war into the webapps folder and run the server with everything working fine.

I am not a user of Eclipse so I might have misunderstood something, but I found that when you create a Tomcat server, it will embed the one you gave it to it. Doing that is a bit of an issue when you are working with logback, because usually you set your logs location directly into the Tomcat folder. And in Eclipse you are working out of this folder.

So, I can't run my application because it can't find the location of the logs folder at the fine place.

Is there a way to use Tomcat in Eclipse like Intellij? Or did I just miss something because I am kind of new with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the FAQ: [(1)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Developing#Developing-Q6) [(2)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ)

> I found that when you create a Tomcat server, it will embed the one you gave it to it.

You have to be more specific with your description. How you do things and what do you see. What do you mean by "embed"? What is the actual failure that you are observing with your logging?

There are different ways to do things.

*For me* by default Eclipse does not embed Tomcat, but runs it as a proper java process. (`org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap`) You should be able to see it with jconsole and similar tools.

It runs your web application expanded, i.e. without zipping it into a war file. It creates a separate configuration of Tomcat, i.e. runs it with separate CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE directories (as documented in RUNNING.txt file of Apache Tomcat). The CATALINA_HOME directory stays untouched and CATALINA_BASE directory is `${workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0` etc. A `logs` directory can be found there.

One known caveat is that java.util.logging is not configured by default (the system properties `java.util.logging.manager` and others are not set). See "How do I enable the JULI logging" item in the FAQ. -- In the same way you will set any other system properties that you may need.

The default configuration of java.util.logging (as provided by JRE) is to log everything to the console, without creating any files.

Comment: When I wrote "embed" I mean that it will not clone the Tomcat folder you gave it to it. In Intellij, it will wrote the war directly into the base Tomcat folder.
Thanks for your answer, I learn some stuff I didn't know. My issue was having no access to the log folder, now I found it, I was able to give access to it.
Last question : is there a way to give admin rights to Eclipse ? So it can write on some files with less access rights ?

Comment: Admin rights? Certainly there is a way, but I won't recommend it. (https://xkcd.com/149/)

Comment: Maybe you will want to learn how to do remote debugging (connecting to an instance of Tomcat launched outside Eclipse): https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Developing#Developing-Debugging

Comment: I understand, but my issue was I got this error message while starting my app :
`ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollingFile] - openFile(../logs/spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\logs\spring.log (Permission denied)`. So do you think there is another way to solve this ?

Comment: Those ".." - The path looks to be relative to the current working directory of the process (as shown by "user.dir" system property in Java). The working directory may be changed in the launch configuration (see JULI reference in my answer). I think that you would better use the system property "catalina.base" to refer to Tomcat configuration root explicitly in your logging config. (Also, why backslashes - '\' - in the path. Is it Windows?)

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows on that computer. Thanks for the advice !

Comment: To "It creates a separate configuration of Tomcat...": Actually, in Eclipse you can _choose_ whether you want to deploy everything directly to the installed Tomcat. You can even choose your own folder for `CATALINA_BASE`. Just double-click the server and you will see all the available options in the opened editor (disabled though when there is already some module deployed).